# rendering username or id in the url with express routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have read some documentation on express routing and I am trying to render the logged in user's username or identification in the url. I need help getting the routing hit in my server.js to render the pages even before authentication. Where am I messing up?

Routing (profile.js)

```
const express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/user");
const passport = require("passport");
const multer = require("multer");

// Profile Avatar
const upload = multer({ dest: "upload" });
// ACCOUNT ROUTES

router
  .route("/profile/:id")
  .get(function (req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      let dateObj = req.user.createdAt;
      let createdDate = dateObj.toString().slice(4, 16);
      let navbarLoggedIn = "partials/loggedIn-navbar.ejs";
      let id = req.params.username;
      console.log(id + "\n");
      res.render(
        "profile",
        { id: req.params.id },
        {
          currentUser: req.user.username,
          currentCompany: req.user.company,
          currentLocation: req.user.location,
          currentPosition: req.user.position,
          memberStatus: createdDate,
          navbar: navbarLoggedIn,
        }
      );
    } else {
      res.redirect("login");
    }
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {});

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const path = require("path");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const logger = require("morgan");
const main = require("./routes/main");
const about = require("./routes/about");
const contact = require("./routes/contact");
const profile = require("./routes/profile");
const pricing = require("./routes/pricing");
const help = require("./routes/help");
const login = require("./routes/login");
const signup = require("./routes/signup");
const forgot_password = require("./routes/forgot-password");
const User = require("./models/user");
const multer = require("multer");

// PORT
const port = 8080;
const app = express();

// COOKIES AND SESSION
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// DATABASE
require("./config/database.js");

// PASSPORT AUTHENTICATION
require("./config/passport.js");

// MIDDLEWARE
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public")));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("view cache", false);

// ROUTES
app.use("/", main);
app.use("/about", about);
app.use("/contact", contact);
app.use("/pricing", pricing);
app.use("/profile/:id", profile, (req, res, next) => {
  next();
});
app.use("/help", help);
app.use("/login", login);
app.use("/signup", signup);
app.use("/forgot-password", forgot_password);



// Logout
app.get("/logout", function (req, res) {
  res.clearCookie("connect.sid");
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(port, (err, done) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log({ message: "success!" });
  } else {
    return err;
  }
});
```

And here is my file structure.[file structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d17A5.png)
[views strucutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iHr8.png)

Comment: Can you show a file structure of your views folder?

Comment: @Tyler2P the views layout should be added now.

Comment: My biggest problem is that in the routing js (profile) since its being exported, I can't use app.get("profile/:id") can I? since if I do it in there it would render as localhost:xxxx/profile/profile/:id causing an error i believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the profile router in your main server file, instead of defining one specific route, define a short prefix. In your case you'll use `/profile`. Then in your router simply define the rest of the route (`/:id`).

Example:
Server:

```js
app.use("/profile", profile, (req, res, next) => {
    next();
});
```

Router:

```js
router
  .route("/:id")
  .get(function (req, res) {
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
          let dateObj = req.user.createdAt;
          let createdDate = dateObj.toString().slice(4, 16);
          let navbarLoggedIn = "partials/loggedIn-navbar.ejs";
          let id = req.params.username;
          console.log(id + "\n");
          res.render(
              "profile",
              {
                  id: req.params.id
              },
              {
                  currentUser: req.user.username,
                  currentCompany: req.user.company,
                  currentLocation: req.user.location,
                  currentPosition: req.user.position,
                  memberStatus: createdDate,
                  navbar: navbarLoggedIn,
              }
          );
      } else {
          res.redirect("login");
      }
  });
```

Comment: this looks good and you can also use middlewares https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html, here you can do some stuff

Comment: @bhavesh When I make the changes and test again, the route is not being hit. I set up a console.log to fire when the route gets hit before anything else is touch and it has not rendered in the logs at all. I do know why but I believe its trying to route as localhostxxxx/:id instead of /profile/id... I believe I have everything scoped correctly too.

Comment: i revise your question , i am not sure this time but i tink the is isseu is app.use("/profile/:id", profile, (req, res, next) => {
  next();
})==> it should be ==> app.use("/profile/:id", profile)

if still issue you can ask

Comment: That is the problem. After working on some other parts of the project, I realized that it is simply because the first route that needs to be hit would have to be "/profile/id", so I would have to change somethings. My only issue would be anchor tags and redirect links. Would all my a-tags an redirect links have to look like <a href="/profile/:id"/>? @bhavesh